# Cocos2d How to make/run animation more realistic

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

Simple Animation - first thought that came up, when 2 objects collided.
For example: Player collides with object Bouncer. What would happen?

1. Player class start bouncing animation
2. Bouncer class start self animation to inform user that bouncing started

this is simple animation that looks pretty good but, I have an idea how to add more realism to this and i want to, ask is it really possible to do this?

Let's say same situation player collided with bouncer

1. Make player invisible
2. In Bouncer class start animation (animation frames painted with Player and Bouncer motion  (e.g preparing for jumping))
3. in step 2 Players position changed, putting players into position where bouncing animation ended
4. Make player visible
5. start Jump

If it is really possible, then i think this will look more realistic. Is there any sample code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Animating anything in Cocos2D can be very time consuming. If you are doing vector/pixel work, you must create a frame for every single change in the animation, which can be very challenging if you don't have much in the way of an artistic background. Might I recommend something like [Adobe Flash](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/downloads.html#flashCS6) which will semi-automate the animation process. It has a function to export the animation to frames (individual PNGs), which could be turn into an animation using CCAnimation and some helper classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your animation using After Effects, for instance, that generates a set o frames. Then you can use a software like Sprite Helper to embed that animation in cocos2d.

On your project you just have to load it and play it when you need.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d